# Circular Aperture Diffraction Pattern

Tags: plotting, special-functions, physics, fourier-analysis, optics

I am unsure if this is even possible in Mathematica, but my optics professor assigned a project to me on circular apertures and Fourier transforms. I have found plenty on the Airy function, but I am wondering if there is any way to produce an image like the one below in Mathematica:

[image]

Comment: Also check out the Wolfram Demonstration [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/2DFourierTransforms/). This gives a variety of examples of how you can use 2D Fourier Transforms to calculate diffraction patterns with different shapes, and sizes of apertures. You can also download the notebook to see how it is coded.

Answer (score 19):

Physicist chiming in - *Hi!*.

I believe there has been some confusion here. It seems to me that OP is meaning to plot an [Airy disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk) which was studied by G.B. Airy but is **not** given by the Airy function. It is given by the Fourier transform of the indicator function of the unit circle, which actually happens to be a Bessel function (see e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Two-dimensional_functions)).

If I understood this right, then the correct solution is as follows:

```
DensityPlot[BesselJ[1, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]/Sqrt[
            x^2 + y^2], {x, -60, 60}, {y, -60, 60}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
            PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

You can play around with the options of `DensityPlot` to increase the contrast, add a legend, or change the colour scheme into something more similar to your intended image. I leave this to you.

--

For the mathematically inclined: we are dealing with what we physicists call [Fraunhofer diffraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_diffraction). Given a profile $f(x_1,x_2)$, the corresponding diffraction pattern is proportional to $\tilde f(\xi_1,\xi_2)$. In our case, the profile is a solid disk, so $f(x_1,x_2)=1_{D(1)}=\theta(1-\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2})$, with $\theta$ the step-function.

Unfortunately,

```
FourierTransform[HeavisideTheta[1 - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, y}, {a, b}]
```

is returned unevaluated. Fortunately, this Fourier integral is a well-known result, the quoted Bessel function. It would be nice to know why MMA is unable to evaluate this classic integral. Oh well.

Comment: @Nasser I just would like to point out that the scale of the OP's plot is logarithmic. I am not sure, but maybe, we need the plot of `Log[Abs[BesselJ[1, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]]`? This might also increase the contrast if neagtive values get truncated somewhere...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I think it's better to plot `Log[Abs[...]+1]` so that $0$ is mapped to $0$. This produces a nicer plot than that without the `+1`

Comment: Appropriate username...

Comment: Well, the Airy pattern is the diffraction pattern calculated as the modulus square of the Fourier transform of a circular aperture, first observed by George Bidell Airy, astronomer of Her Majesty. Basically, is the diffraction pattern of circular aperture in the Fraunhofer regime. If someone uses `Log[Abs[...]+1]` take into account this is just for incresing the visibility of the secondary rings, not often visible.This means that the pattern is not really that.

Comment: That `FourierTransform` returns unevaluated, but you can always do it in spherical coordinates: `Integrate[r Exp[I k r Cos[f]], {r, 0, 1}, {f, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 Assumptions -> k > 0]`.

Comment: `FourierTransform[UnitStep[1 - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, y}, {a, b}]` evaluates to the expected answer. Why the `HeavisideTheta[]` version doesn't should prolly be reported to support.

Comment: @J. M. Thanks. For the record, your approach doesn't evaluate in my version of MMA either (10.4 for Windows).

Comment: Huh. That one works in 11.2. O well...

Comment: `FourierTransform[HeavisideTheta[1 - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, y}, {a, b}]` works for me in 11.3 and 11.2. BTW, you can also use `HankelTransform` to get the required answer: `HankelTransform[HeavisideTheta[1 - r], r, k]`.

Comment: Just a note of caution: what is said in this answer is misleading. There is a difference between the diffracted field and the resulting pattern irradiance. I can see that my comment above was ignored. As a physicist and expert in this field, I could not avoid advising it.

Comment: Hi @JoséAntonioDíazNavas, nice to see a fellow physicist (*also from Spain* :-) ) here! Anyway, you mean that the pattern is $|f|^2$, and not $f$ itself, right? Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: Please, revise your notes in Optics, and for the God sake! As a physicist, do not reference Wikipedia :))...

Answer (score 12):

I feel a bit bad about sliding in so lately. @Nasser's answer was already very good. However, the function is very oscillatory, so I thought it might be a better idea to use a `Texture` to render it. I use `ParametricPlot` for that along with a suitable `TextureCoordinateFunction`. Since the function is radially symmetric, the texture needs only be produced for a very narrow strip. This is done by the function `tex`.

```
R = 20;(*half box size*)
n = 1000;(*resolution of texture*)
x0 = N[Range[0, R, R/n]];
tex = cut \[Function] Module[{c, cols}, 
    c = Map[ 
      r \[Function] If[Abs[r] <= 10^-12, 0., Max[cut, Log10[Abs[2.0 BesselJ[1, Pi r]/(Pi r)]]]], 
      Sqrt[2.] x0
      ];
    cols = ColorData["SunsetColors"] /@ Rescale[c];
    Image[ConstantArray[Developer`ToPackedArray[List @@@ (cols)], 10]]];
texfun = {x, y, u, v} \[Function] Evaluate[{Sqrt[(u^2 + v^2)]/R/Sqrt[2], 0.5}];
plot = cut \[Function] ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, -R, R}, {y, -R, R},
    TextureCoordinateFunction -> texfun, 
    TextureCoordinateScaling -> False,
    PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], Texture[tex[cut]]},
    BoundaryStyle -> None,
    PlotPoints -> 100,
    PlotRangePadding -> 0, Axes -> False];
```

Moreover, `tex` produces a logarithmic texture where all values below the truncation argument `cut` are replaced by `cut`. The effect of different truncatations can be seen below:

```
g = GraphicsGrid[Partition[
   Table[
    plot[cut],
    {cut, {-1., -1.5, -2., -2.5, -3., -3.5}}
    ],
   3], ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: Here's another one abusing symmetry:`ParametricPlot[r {Cos[f], Sin[f]}, {r, .01, 5}, {f, 0, 2 Pi},
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, r, f}, 
   ColorData["SunsetColors"][2 Abs[BesselJ[1, Pi r]/(Pi r)]]]
 , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
 , Axes -> False
 , BoundaryStyle -> None
 , Epilog -> {Thick, Circle[{0, 0}, 5]} 
 ]`

Answer (score 7):

The Fourier transforms of Airy function is given by what is called [Sombrero function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sombrero_function)

So here is something to get you started. This finds the radius to each pixel over some square region and applies the definition of `Sombrero` and plots the result using `ListDensityPlot`

```
meshgrid[x_List,y_List]:={ConstantArray[x,Length[x]],Transpose@ConstantArray[y,Length[y]]};

n       = 50; (* grid size *)
z       = 1/2; (*adjust as needed*)
x0      = Range[1,n,z]-n/2; (*shift center*)
{xx,yy} = meshgrid[x0,x0]; 
r       = Sqrt[xx^2+yy^2];  (*radius*)
sombro  = Map[ If[#==0,0,2.0 BesselJ[1,Pi #]/(Pi #)]&,r,{2}];

ListDensityPlot[sombro,ColorFunction->"SunsetColors"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can play with different plots or option to make it closer to what you showed. For example, using `z=1/4` or different `n`  or other scaling one can do.

Comment: The only sombrero (hat) function I know is the Mexican hat, i.e., the Laplacian of a 2D Gaussian function. I never heard about this. :))

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas Nah, the _one and only_ Mexican hat is $f(x,y,z) = a r^4 - b r^2$. Also known as Landau potential... ;o)

Comment: hats off to potential.

Answer (score 6):

I can't improve on the great plots already presented, but MMA can indeed solve the problem.  Start with an energy wave from a circular aperture

```
Eeq=dE==A dx dy Sin[2Pi f t-(2\[Pi] r)/lambda]
```

Point P on the observation screen has coordinates X, Y, Z, with the origin at the center of the aperture.
Z is the distance from the center of the aperture to the center of the screen.
Distance from center of aperture to point P on screen `r0` is

```
r0=Sqrt[X^2+Y^2+Z^2]
```

Dist r, from a point x,y,0 on the aperture to Point P on the screen is

```
r=Sqrt[(X-x)^2+(Y-y)^2+Z^2]
```

Use the small aperture approximation to make simplifications

```
rhs=(r^2-r0^2//ExpandAll)/.{x^2->0,y^2->0}

Clear[r,r0]

r^2-r0^2//Factor
(*(r-r0) (r+r0)*)

lhs=(%/.r+r0->2r0)

Solve[lhs==rhs,r]//Flatten

Rrule=r->r0-(x X+y Y)/r0

Eeq=Eeq/.Rrule 
 (* dE==A dx dy Sin[2 Pi f t-(2 Pi (r0-(x X+y Y)/r0))/lambda] *)
```

Convert from x, y on the aperture to rho, phi
and X, Y on the screen to R Phi.

```
x=rho Cos[phi];
y=rho Sin[phi];
X=R Cos[Phi];
Y=R Sin[Phi];

Eeq
(* dE==A dx dy Sin[2 \[Pi] f t-(2 \[Pi] (r0-(R rho Sin[phi] Sin[Phi]+R rho Cos[phi] Cos[Phi])/r0))/lambda] *)
```

Since the diffraction pattern is symmetric about `Phi`, simplify by setting `Phi` to 0.

```
Eeq=Eeq/.Phi->0//ExpandAll   

(*-A dx dy Sin[-(2 Pi f t)-(2 Pi R rho Cos[phi])/(lambda r0)+(2 Pi r0)/lambda]*) 

Eeq=A dx dy Sin[2 Pi f t+(2 Pi R rho Cos[phi])/(lambda r0)-(2 Pi r0)/lambda]//.{-2 f Pi t+(2 Pi r0)/lambda->alpha,-((2 Pi R rho  Cos[phi])/(lambda r0))->beta}//TrigExpand;

Eeq=%/.{alpha->-2 f Pi t+(2 Pi r0)/lambda,beta->-((2 Pi R rho  Cos[phi])/(lambda r0))}
```

Integrate over the aperture of radius a in cylindrical coordinates, dx dy -> rho drho dphi.

```
Eeq=%/.dx dy->rho drho dphi

(*A dphi drho rho Cos[(2 Pi r0)/lambda-2 \[Pi] f t] Sin[(2 Pi R rho Cos[phi])/(lambda r0)]-A dphi drho rho Sin[(2 Pi r0)/lambda-2 Pi f t] Cos[(2 Pi R rho Cos[phi])/(lambda r0)]*)

$Assumptions=a>0&&R>0&&lambda>0&&r0>0
```

Works in the following form:

```
En=A  Cos[(2 Pi r0)/lambda-2 Pi f t]Integrate[rho Sin[(2 Pi R rho Cos[phi])/(lambda r0)],{phi,0,2 Pi},{rho,0,a}]-A Sin[(2 Pi r0)/lambda-2 Pi f t] Integrate[rho Cos[(2 Pi R rho Cos[phi])/(lambda r0)],{phi,0,2 Pi},{rho,0,a}]

(*-((a A lambda r0 BesselJ[1,(2 a Pi R)/(lambda r0)] Sin[(2 Pi r0)/lambda-2 Pi f t])/R)*)
```

Remember that R is the radial distance from the center of the screen to the observation pt. Get to the familiar form by

```
En/.R->(lambda r0 xx)/(2 a Pi)

(*-((2 Pi a^2 A BesselJ[1,xx] Sin[(2 Pi r0)/lambda-2 Pi f t])/xx)*)
```