# It is possible to generate a diffraction plot from the equation

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, graphics, calculus-and-analysis, physics

I have this equation $$ D = 1.22 \frac{\lambda f}{R_{0} \sqrt{1+2 \alpha\Delta T}} $$ in which D is the diameter of the circular opening, and the parameters I want to vary to analyze the diffraction figure are wavelength $(\lambda)$, focal length $(f)$, initial aperture radius $(R_{0})$, expansion coefficient $(\alpha)$, temperature variation $(\Delta T)$.

First, I want to vary the value of $R_{0}$, and keep the values of $\alpha$ and $\Delta T$ fixed.

Second, I want to vary the value of $\alpha$, and keep the values of $R_{0}$ and $\Delta T$ fixed.

Third, I want to vary the value of $\Delta T$, and keep the values of $R_{0}$ and $\alpha$ fixed.

Is there a way to make a program like this and have it return the values of D and a graph with the modification that the diffraction figure underwent in these cases?

The diffraction figure is something like

[image]

The parameter values, for the wavelength: $\lambda = 514 nm $, $\lambda = 632 nm $, $\lambda = 750 nm $,
for focal length: $f = 2 cm$, $f = 10 cm$, $f = 15 cm$,
for the coefficient $\alpha = 8.6*10^{-6}$, $\alpha = 25*10^{-6}$, $\alpha = 18*10^{-6}$

Ranging $R_{0}$ in a range from 1mm to 10mm, fixed $\alpha = 8.6*10^{-6}$ and $\Delta T = 1$

Ranging from $\alpha$ to $\alpha = 8.6 * 10^{-6}$, $\alpha = 25*10^{-6}$, $\alpha = 18*10^{-6}$, fixed $R_{0}= 1mm$ and $\Delta T = 1$

Ranging $\Delta T$ from 0.1 to 1, fixed $R_{0} = 1mm$ and $\alpha = 8.6*10^{-6} $.

At first it would be that, but the idea is that I can change these values later in the program as I do more experiments.

Comment: You have not defined nor provided an example of what you mean by a "diffraction figure". When you vary the parameters, what range do you want for each parameter? For when the parameters are fixed, what are the fixed values?

Comment: Thank you very much, I edited the issue with your comments

Comment: This might be related.  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160913/circular-aperture-diffraction-pattern/160974#160974

Answer (score 2):

The formula that you provided does not appear to correspond to the diffraction figures that you provided. I have provided an interactive plot for the formula that you provided.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Manipulate[
 Module[{plt},
  d[λ_, f_, R0_, α_, ΔT_] :=
   1.22 λ f/(Quantity[R0, "Millimeter"] Sqrt[1 + 2 α ΔT]);
  Switch[calc,
   1, α = 8.6*10^-6; ΔT = 1.;
   plt = Plot[
     UnitConvert[d[λ, f, R0v, α, ΔT], "Micrometers"],
     {R0v, 1, 10},
     PlotRange -> All,
     Frame -> True,
     FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
        {StringForm[
          "``, aperture radius (mm)", Subscript[R, 0]], 
         "D, diameter of opening (µm)"}),
     Epilog -> {Red, Thick, 
       Line[{{R0, 0}, {R0, 
          QuantityMagnitude@
           UnitConvert[d[λ, f, R0, α, ΔT], "Micrometers"]}}]},
     ImageSize -> Medium],
   2, R0 = 1; ΔT = 1.;
   plt = Plot[
     UnitConvert[d[λ, f, R0, αv, ΔT], "Micrometers"],
     {αv, 6.5*10^-6, 30*10^-6},
     PlotRange -> All,
     Frame -> True,
     FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
        {"α, coefficient", 
         "D, diameter of opening (µm)"}),
     ImageSize -> Medium,
     Epilog -> {Red, Thick, 
       Line[{{#, 0}, {#, 
            QuantityMagnitude@
             UnitConvert[d[λ, f, R0, #, ΔT], "Micrometers"]}}] & /@
        {8.6*10^-6, 18*10^-6, 25*10^-6}}],
   3, R0 = 1; α = 8.6*10^-6;
   plt = Plot[
     UnitConvert[d[λ, f, R0, α, ΔTv], "Micrometers"],
     {ΔTv, 0.1, 1},
     PlotRange -> All,
     Frame -> True,
     FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, 
          Bold] & /@
        {"ΔT, temperature variation",
         "D, diameter of opening (µm)"}),
     Epilog -> {Red, Thick, 
       Line[{{ΔT, 0}, {ΔT, 
          QuantityMagnitude@
           UnitConvert[d[λ, f, R0, α, ΔT], "Micrometers"]}}]},
     ImageSize -> Medium]];
  Show@plt],
 {{λ, Quantity[514, "Nanometers"], "wavelength, λ"},
  {Quantity[514, "Nanometers"], Quantity[632, "Nanometers"], 
   Quantity[750, "Nanometers"]}},
 {{f, Quantity[2, "Centimeters"], "focal length, f"},
  {Quantity[2, "Centimeters"], Quantity[10, "Centimeters"], 
   Quantity[15, "Centimeters"]}},
 {{α, 8.6*10^-6, "coefficient, α"}, {8.6*10^-6 -> 
    EngineeringForm[8.6*10^-6], (18*10^-6) -> 
    EngineeringForm[18.*10^-6], (25*10^-6) -> EngineeringForm[25.*10^-6]}},
 {{R0, 5.5, StringForm["aperture radius, `` (mm)", Subscript[R, 0]]}, 1, 10, 
  0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ΔT, 0.1, "temperature variation, ΔT"}, 0.1, 1, 
  0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{calc, 1, "calculation"}, {1 -> 
    StringForm["vary ``; α and ΔT fixed", Subscript[R, 0]],
   2 -> StringForm["vary α; `` and ΔT fixed", Subscript[R, 0]],
   3 -> StringForm["vary ΔT; `` and α fixed", Subscript[R, 0]]},
  ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

[image]